# How to implement ACL for Repository?

Tags: design-patterns

I am creating a dashboard. I obviously need to fetch some data. The problem is the data shown is based on user role.

For instance:

- Administrator can see everything and columns that are fetched from database are x, y and z.
- Manager can see only rows for users that belongs to his region and columns that are fetched are only x and y.
- Employee can see only rows that belongs to him and only column x.

*The narrowing is accidental. Admin as well might see one column and Manager ten.*

So basically the number of rows and columns differ based on role.

I want to avoid single method in repository with a bunch of if statements. I would like to design this in a way that allows me to add roles in accordance with the SRP and OCP.

Maybe chain of responsibility is a good solution? I would create a bunch of Query objects with a method canHandle that would check user role?

This is my current solution: [github](https://github.com/3amprogrammer/dashslab.io/tree/master/app/Dashboard)